# Kombu in non-blocking way

Tags: python, tornado, kombu

I am looking for a way to use kombu as MQ adapter between tornado-sockjs and Django application server. I did something like:

```
class BrokerClient(ConsumerMixin):
    clients = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = BrokerConnection(settings.BROKER_URL)
        self.io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        self.queue = sockjs_queue
        self._handle_loop()

    @staticmethod
    def instance():
        if not hasattr(BrokerClient, '_instance'):
            BrokerClient._instance = BrokerClient()
        return BrokerClient._instance

    def add_client(self, client):
        self.clients.append(client)

    def remove_client(self, client):
        self.clients.remove(client)

    def _handle_loop(self):
        try:
            if self.restart_limit.can_consume(1):
                for _ in self.consume(limit=5):
                    pass
        except self.connection.connection_errors:
            print ('Connection to broker lost. '
             'Trying to re-establish the connection...')
        self.io_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(0.0001), self._handle_loop)

    def get_consumers(self, Consumer, channel):
        return [Consumer([self.queue, ], callbacks=[self.process_task])]

    def process_task(self, body, message):
        for client in self.clients:
            if hasattr(body, 'users') and client.user.pk in body.users:
                client.send(body)
        message.ack()
```

But tornado blocked at _handle_loop execution (as expected).

Is there any way to prevent this?

I am aware of Pika library adapter for Tornado, but I would like to use kombu because it's already used in project and has flexible transports.

UPDATE:

Changed _handle_loop to generator function

```
def drain_events(self, callback):
    with self.Consumer() as (connection, channel, consumers):
        with self.extra_context(connection, channel):
            try:
                connection.drain_events(timeout=1)
            except:
                pass
    callback(None)


@tornado.gen.engine
def _handle_loop(self):
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.drain_events)
    self.io_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(0.0001), self._handle_loop)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the correct solution for RabbitMQ backend:

```
class BrokerClient(object):
    clients = []

    @staticmethod
    def instance():
        if not hasattr(BrokerClient, '_instance'):
            BrokerClient._instance = BrokerClient()
        return BrokerClient._instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = BrokerConnection(settings.BROKER_URL)
        self.consumer = Consumer(self.connection.channel(), [queue, ], callbacks=[self.process_task])
        self.consumer.consume()
        io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        for sock, handler in self.connection.eventmap.items():
            def drain_nowait(fd, events):
                handler()
            io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), drain_nowait, l.READ | l.ERROR)

    def process_task(self, body, message):
        #something
        message.ack()

    def add_client(self, client):
        self.clients.append(client)

    def remove_client(self, client):
        self.clients.remove(client)
```

For other backends, you can use the solution posted in the question

NOTE: Doesn't work with librabbitmq

Comment: NOTE: At the time of this writing, the latest py-amqp and kombu do not officially support asynchronous reads. [see this](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/issues/25). However, there are [breadcrumbs](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/master/examples/experimental/async_consume.py) for async consumptions

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need, to switch in a non-blocking way between Kombu/RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ. The solution was to use Gevent to monkey patch the socket libraries so Kombu would become non-blocking aswell. My "main" thread had the Kombu drain_events callback running, and in another gevent thread I had a loop that was receiving messages from a ZeroMQ socket. Worked well.

This also does not work with librabbitmq as it does its own socket stuff in C that is not affected by Gevent.